# create a list of variables in R for use in formula

Tags: r, regression

I have a dataframe `dm` with some dummy variables, `d1`, `d2`, `d3`. I would like to create a list of them, `dummies`, and use it in a simple way like

```
lm(y~dummies+x,data=dm)
```

Is it possible?

I have found two ways but i don't like them:

1. Create an additional dataframe `dummies`.
2. Use something like `formula(paste('y~',dummies,...)`

The first approach eats memory, the second one is just ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'd go on the second way, no problem with that.

Comment: Remove all other columns from `data`, then use `formula = y ~ .`

Comment: `formula` is the standard R method, regardless of your aesthetic opinion. To implement Andrie's method you can use a subset data argument inside `lm`:   `data=subset(dm, select( c(y,dummies) )`

Comment: @DWin That's a nice idiom, but I think you meant `data=subset(dm, select=c(y, dummies))`, or indeed `data=dm[, c("y", "dummies")]` which will be safer, given the inherent dangers of `subset`.

Comment: Agree to your first. Regarding the second option, I do not think "dummies" would get expanded and should have been `names(dummies)` unquoted.

Comment: @DWin, Thanks for the method with subset. Maybe i was imprecise. I would like to achieve something like `lm(y~dummies+x,data=dm)` and `lm(y~dummies+log(x),data=dm)`. Is this possible without creating a new dataset and parsing string into formula?

Comment: I cannot think of any method that would not involve parsing "strings" (not a well defined term in R-speak) or expressions. You _should_ edit your question to make that request. Putting it in the comments will be less effective at getting people to look at it.

Answer (score 4):

Construct a data frame that contains only the variables of interest, then use `y ~ .`, indicating to use all columns in the data frame.

For example:

```
set.seed(1)
dm <- data.frame(
  y = rnorm(100),
  x = rnorm(100),
  d1 = sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE),
  d2 = sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE),
  d3 = sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE)
)

lm(y ~ ., dm)
lm(formula = y ~ ., data = dm)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x           d1           d2           d3  
  -0.089440    -0.012945    -0.006305     0.391576    -0.034225
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that is not what i'm searching for. I don't wish to create an additional dataframe. My goal is to use the set of dummies and try different regressors in a beautiful way. Say, something like `lm(y~dummies+x,data=dm)` and later `lm(y~dummies+z,data=dm)`.